# Installing Fedora 19: only shows one SSD of two

Tags: installation, ssd, raid-1, fedora-19

I'm trying to install Fedora 19 on two SSDs (Software RAID 1 if possible). These SSDs were used in another computer before. I deleted the MBR record and the partition table with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1` where X is either a or b for the device file.

Fdisk now shows both SSDs with no partitions:

```
[root@localhost liveuser]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 62.9 GB, 62879923712 bytes, 122812351 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 62.9 GB, 62881005568 bytes, 122814464 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

However, the installer only shows one of both SSDs: 
[image: installer screenshot]

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that the installer previously didn't recognize any of my two SSDs. But that was before I overwrote the MBR and partition table using `dd`. It seems to have solved that problem for /dev/sda but not for /dev/sdb. I wonder what might cause this. If it was a driver, it shouldn't recognize any of the SSDs, right?

**UPDATE**
Apparently, the installer thinks that `/dev/sdb`is in a RAID. I just took a look into `/var/log/messages` and found this (notice: the first time, I run the egrep command before starting the installation wizard, the second time I started the installation wizard and clicked it through to the disc menu seen in the screenshot above):

```
[root@localhost liveuser]# egrep '/dev/sd[a|b]' /var/log/messages
[root@localhost liveuser]# egrep '/dev/sd[a|b]' /var/log/messages
Sep 11 21:35:56 localhost /etc/gdm/Xsession[1107]: ERROR: ddf1: wrong # of devices in RAID set "ddf1_ffffffffffffffffab114064ab1140648b6517008b650000" [1/2] on /dev/sdb
Sep 11 21:35:56 localhost /etc/gdm/Xsession[1107]: /dev/sdb: "isw" and "ddf1" formats discovered (using ddf1)!
Sep 11 21:36:01 localhost program: Running... multipath -c /dev/sda
Sep 11 21:36:01 localhost program: /dev/sda is not a valid multipath device path
Sep 11 21:36:02 localhost /etc/gdm/Xsession[1107]: ERROR: ddf1: wrong # of devices in RAID set "ddf1_ffffffffffffffffab114064ab1140648b6517008b650000" [1/2] on /dev/sdb
```

What could cause this behavior? The motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-8I915PM-FS from a Fujitsu Siemens computer with no RAID capabilities. I also haven't set up a software RAID yet.

**What can I do to let Fedora find the second SSD?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow fixed this now.

At first, I read somewhere (sorry, forgot where), that used (SSD) disks sometimes have this problem and you could get rid of it by filling the disk with zeros or using `dmraid -r -E /dev/sdb` to erase the RAID information. But these two approaches didn't work here.

I just installed gparted with fedora 19 live cd, initialized each of the SSDs with a msdos partition table and created one big ext2 partition on both disks. I suppose the filesystem is not important and you could probably do this also with tools like fdisk and mkfs (which gparted uses in the background AFAIK).

This made both disks available to the installer.